# jquery ajax request a database column

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, database

I want to take a column data from my database using a jquery ajax request but i fail everytime. What i do wrong? Basically i press a button and i request an array with the values.

javascript :

```
$("#player-button").click(function() {
         $.ajax({   
        type: "GET",
        url: "homesearchplayers.php",            
        dataType: "text",                
        success: function(response){                     
            alert(response);
        }

    });
   });
```

html:

```
<div id="player-button-block">
               <input type='button' id="player-button" value='Find Nearby Players' >
        </div>
```

php:

```
<?php

    include 'dbconnect.php';

    $query = "SELECT userPos FROM users"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
           $storeArray[] =  $row['userPos'];  
    }
echo  "$storeArray";

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: what you want to display with "$storeArray"

Comment: all the values from userPos column in an array way

Comment: for priniting array you should use `var_dump()`, `echo` is used to print strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

    include 'dbconnect.php';

    $query = "SELECT userPos FROM users"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
           $storeArray[] =  $row['userPos'];  
    }


  var_dump($storeArray);exit;
// here array data will be dump

    mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
```